# Update apk to playstore

Tags: react-native, google-play

Previously I uploaded apk to playstore that I developed using Ionic. Now I converted that project into React Native. Can I upload apk(using React Native) as an update of Previous application that developed using Ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upload the APK in playstore, i've also did something similiar with expo and now swicthed to bare react native.
THings to keep in mind before uploading :

1. Same certificate should be used as that of previous app
2. Same bundle Id should be used
3. Increment the build version in build.gradle file

hope it helps, feel free for doubts,

Comment: I try to upload using the same application Id and Increment the versionCode and versionName also. But playsote shows errors "You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):"

Comment: thats what i mentioned in first point. the certificate should be same as that of previous app.

Comment: How can I check the previous app certificate? Did you mean .keystore details?

Comment: there should be .jks file that contains the certificate. that should be used here too

Comment: I used to this doc to build apk(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android).  And I used previous passwords to generate this keystore.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, I have two questions related, 1) when I upload apk for the first time and later i do some changes in my app and want to re-upload it so how can i handle the version in RN (1.0.0, 1.1.0) then update it in the play store, 2) How can i tell users its an update check out it as a modal inside the app!

Comment: @DevAS what exactly do you want to upgrade? there is always a build version in build.gradle where you can specify the version

Comment: @GauravRoy UH, I have an app in play store and I want to add a new version of it so should I remove the old app from the play store then upload the new version and so on in the coming updates or there is a way to handle these? another question is "How can I tell the users a new version available now "  like [this](https://droidmentor.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Example.jpg)